# LookUpSet - Count Items Returned

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report with 2 datasets on different servers. I have used the following expression to get data from one of the datasets:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!field1.Value, Fields!field_1.Value, Fields!submitted.Value, "DataSet1"),",")
```

This gives me all the values expected, but how do I Count these values?

I have tried

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!field1.Value, Fields!field_1.Value, Fields!submitted.Value, "DataSet1"),",").Length
```

and this just counts every character in the returned values rather than those separated by a comma.

and I have tried

```
=Count(=Join(LookupSet(Fields!field1.Value, Fields!field_1.Value, Fields!submitted.Value, "DataSet1"),","))
```

but this just gives 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of items in the array, use:

```
=LookupSet(Fields!field1.Value
  , Fields!field_1.Value
  , Fields!submitted.Value
  , "DataSet1").Length
```

It looks like you were trying to apply your count to the `Join` result, but this will be a string, and you want to look at the array, i.e. just apply `Length` to the `LookupSet` result.

Comment: May I know how to get the last value within a lookupset?